# How to change collisionPolygon shape using set_deferred?

Tags: godot, gdscript

I'm trying to change my `CollisionPolygon2D` shape via code as such:

```
...

self.polygon[0].x+=100
```

but it gives the error:

> area_set_shape_disabled: Can't change this state while flushing
> queries. Use call_deferred() or set_deferred() to change monitoring
> state instead.

which is why I'm assuming I'll need to use `set_deferred()` to change the shape
so how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be useful to use this pattern:

1. Get a copy of the value
2. Modify the temporary value
3. Set the value back

```
var temp_polygon = get_polygon()
temp_polygon[0].x -= 100
call_deferred("set_polygon", temp_polygon)
```

`call_deferred` is a function that calls functions by name. Here the name was `"set_polygon"` and the second argument is the argument for `set_polygon`. It calls the function later in order to avoid conflicts like this. I would prefer `call_deferred` over `set_deferred` because the setter function is less likely to cause problems as well.

As a final note, try to avoid directly accessing properties, and use the setter and getter functions when possible.

Comment: this seems a little inefficient, like making a copy and then assigning it, is there any way to directly change the value of the polygon? Also can you elaborate how I could use setter to modify only 1 point of the polygon? or  is it even possible? Also I tried [this](https://pastecode.io/s/gren1wwy) and it seemed to work, is it valid?

Comment: What you wrote is valid. The issue you were having is pretty much the reason why one should use the setter, so if call deferred fixes it, that's a good solution. For some reason I assumed you would want to modify multiple vertices, and if you want to worry about the cost of tiny operations, I think several function calls likely take longer than copying some array elements. Instead of speculating about things that might be "expensive" I'd recommend coding it the most readable or easiest way, and using a profiler to determine what needs to be optimized.